# Codrops Website tour Next previous buttons

Tags: jquery, css, gallery

CoDrops have a website tour built in jQuery, located here - http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

But - when one click on "Start the tour", you get a Next button, which will obviously display the next tour walkthrough. When you click on next again, it'll replace the Next button with a Previous button

It's kind of awkward if you concentrate on the tour and not the controls, because once youve clicked on the first Next button, the Previous button will be below the mouse arrow, and if you dont concentrate, youll just toggle back and forth with the first next and previous button.

I would like to have the Previous button there from the start, but it's got to be dimmed and not clickable. Is this possible?

Theres a comment about it located here too - but no answer yet - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/comment-page-1/#comment-11411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution might be to set CSS visibility to hidden. The element will still occupy the space it would if you could see it, but will not be visible or clickable. Set the visibility property to visible when you want to show it.